# Axios cancel token cancelling every request

Tags: reactjs, axios, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token, request-cancelling

I' trying to implement cancelToken API so that whenever i'm making a request to server to fetch results on every key stroke, only the last request should get processed, however i have implemented the axios cancel token API and it seems to cancel every request, what am i doing wrong here? This function is getting called on every key stroke.

```
getProductLists2 = async () => {


        let formData = new FormData()

        const { start, limit } = this.state

        formData.append('start', start)
        formData.append('limit', limit)

        formData.append('product_title', this.state.searchTitle)
        formData.append('product_sku', this.state.searchSKU)

        let cancel;

        Axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: BASE_URL + '/listProduct',
            // headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
            data: formData,
            cancelToken: new Axios.CancelToken(c => cancel = c)
        })
            .then(products => {
                if (products && products.data.productList && products.data.productList.length > 0) {
                    this.setState({ productList: products.data.productList, totalProducts: products.data.productTotal })
                }
            })
            .catch(err => toast.error('Something went wrong'))
        console.log(cancel, 'h')
        cancel && cancel()
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should cancel the previous cancelToken **before** making a new axios call. When you make you first request, save the cancelToken. Then when you make the second request, check if there already is a cancelToken and cancel it, then make your second axios call.

It also might be a good idea to debounce your getProductLists2 to limit the rate of calls

This is how I do it:

```
    // Cancel the previous axios token if any
    if (this.cancel) this.cancel.cancel();
    // Get a new token
    this.cancel = axios.CancelToken.source();
    axios
        .get(myURL, { cancelToken: this.cancel.token })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
```

Comment: You mentioned debouncing the function, i was wondering won't it slow down the user experience? it already takes some time to fetch the results, adding some delay in my opinion just slows down the whole procedure?

Comment: Indeed it will add a slight delay to the response but at the same time this will prevent unnecessary network and backend activity. You just have to find the right compromise. I usually set mine to 50ms